# Mysql group by help

Tags: mysql

after several attempts, I can not solve this problem.
I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT
                  date_format(connect_time,"%Y-%m-%d %H") AS date,
                  NotConnected,
                  count(id) as calls,
                  sum(`duration`)/60 as minutes
   FROM test.`CDR_Vendors`,

   (SELECT        
       date_format(connect_time,"%Y-%m-%d %H") AS date,
       Count(id) as NotConnected
       FROM `CDR_Vendors_Failed`
       inner join Vendors on (CDR_Vendors_Failed.i_vendor = Vendors.i_vendor)
       inner join Customers on (CDR_Vendors_Failed.i_customer = Customers.i_customer)
       WHERE
       Customers.name like "W%"
       and
       Vendors.name like "D%"
       and connect_time between curdate() and now()
       GROUP by date
       ORDER BY date

   )Failed
       inner join Vendors on (CDR_Vendors.i_vendor = Vendors.i_vendor)
       inner join Customers on (CDR_Vendors.i_customer = Customers.i_customer)
       WHERE
       Customers.name like "W%"
       and
       Vendors.name like "D%"
       and connect_time between curdate() and now()
       GROUP by date
       ORDER BY date
```

The result:

```
date,Notconnected,calls, minutes
'2010-10-25 00', 408, 900, 6611.00
'2010-10-25 01', 408, 456, 2777.60
'2010-10-25 02', 408, 204, 1545.80
'2010-10-25 03', 408, 108, 1951.80
'2010-10-25 04', 408, 192, 895.60
'2010-10-25 05', 408, 300, 544.20
'2010-10-25 06', 408, 540, 961.20
'2010-10-25 07', 408, 1728, 5027.60
'2010-10-25 08', 408, 4968, 20986.40
'2010-10-25 09', 408, 7884, 33065.00
'2010-10-25 10', 408, 7836, 28182.20
'2010-10-25 11', 408, 1800, 3587.80
```

I noticed that the first value of Notconnected field is repeated.

how can I fix this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will be very slow. In which table do you have connect_time field? If in CDR_Vendoes and CRD_Vendors_Failed, then you don't need subquery.

Maybe you need join with CDR_Vendors_Failed table?

```
SELECT
                  date_format(connect_time,"%Y-%m-%d %H") AS date,
                  Failed.NotConnected,
                  count(id) as calls,
                  sum(`duration`)/60 as minutes
   FROM test.`CDR_Vendors`
       inner join Vendors on (CDR_Vendors.i_vendor = Vendors.i_vendor)
       inner join Customers on (CDR_Vendors.i_customer = Customers.i_customer)
       inner join
          (SELECT        
               date_format(connect_time,"%Y-%m-%d %H") AS date,
               Count(id) as NotConnected
               FROM `CDR_Vendors_Failed`
               inner join Vendors on (CDR_Vendors_Failed.i_vendor = Vendors.i_vendor)
               inner join Customers on (CDR_Vendors_Failed.i_customer = Customers.i_customer)
               WHERE
               Customers.name like "W%"
               and
               Vendors.name like "D%"
               and connect_time between curdate() and now()
               GROUP by date
               ORDER BY date
            )Failed on Failed.date = date_format(connect_time,"%Y-%m-%d %H")
       WHERE
       Customers.name like "W%"
       and
       Vendors.name like "D%"
       and connect_time between curdate() and now()
       GROUP by date
       ORDER BY date
```

Comment: then you don't need this big subquery, join with cdr_vendors_failed is enough

Comment: the Query is very slow, how can i join with cdr_vendors_failed ?

Comment: I said that it will be slow. Join like other tables: inner join cdr_vendors_failed on CDR_Vendors.i_customer = CDR_Vendors_Failed.i_customer (or other field), without subquery.

Comment: still very slow and no results whene  inner join CDR_Vendors_Failed on CDR_Vendors.i_customer = CDR_Vendors_Failed.i_customer or any other field

Comment: 4 joins with 2 like conditions in where clause always will be slow, especially if you use mysql and have many data rows in your tables. Maybe you can change table engine type or expect your db for better performance. By the way, your question was about repeated data in "notconnected" field.